# Can I force column to emit whitespaces instead of tabs?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, columns, whitespace, tabulation

I'd like to tabularize a file with the `column` command:

```
$ column -c 60 file.txt
```

The output is nice on the screen, but unusable for my purposes because the items are seperated by tabs. for further processing, I need them as whitespace.

Of course, I cannot just replace one tab with one space because this would destroy the left-alignment of the 2nd, 3rd etc column.

Comment: `expand` from GNU `coreutils` converts tabs to spaces.  There are many other ways, f.i. using Vim.

Comment: You did see the `-s` option in the manpage, did you?

Comment: Yes, I did. In mine, it says *Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.*.

Comment: As you didn't give any examples of input and expected output, this may be what you need, or not. For me, `column -t -s ' '` works insofar as it uses spaces instead of tabs as column separators. As the manpage describes: "-t [...] Useful for pretty-printing displays.".

Comment: Yes, `-s` works well with `-t` but I am not asking for *input* seperators, but for *output* seperators. Apologies if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely this is as simple as mentioned in the first comment. But here it is, spelled out:

```
column -c 60 file.txt | expand
```